# Does a parent object share its NetworkIdentity component with its child objects?

Tags: networking, unity-game-engine

I have set `Player Prefab` of `NetworkManager` as `MyPlayer` object, the `MyPlayer` object has `NetworkIdentity`, and four level child object, I am confused about whether to add `NetworkIdentity` to `M9_anim` object in fourth level child object, then add the `M9_anim`object to `Registered Spawnable Prefabs` list of NetworkManager.

I refer to the instruction, [Setting up a Multiplayer Project from Scratch](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UNetSetup.html).

I learned from unity manual that `NetworkBehaviour` must work with `NetworkIdentity`, I wanna use `NetworkBehaviour` in script component of `M9_anim` child object. So here is the question.

### update

Written in Unity manual, NetworkBehaviours are special scripts that work with objects with the NetworkIdentity component.

So if the child object `M9_anim` need a NetworkBehaviour script component, which must own a NetworkIdentity component beforehand.

Comment: Does your child object rotate or move without parent?

Comment: Transform component is ok. @BarışÇırıka